# How to display graph on another file that has been save? (Python)

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm using `pylab`. So is it using `from show_graph import display` ?

```
from pylab import *
from numpy import outer
from show_graph import display
rc('text', usetex=False)
a=outer(arange(0,1,0.01),ones(10))
figure(figsize=(10,5))
subplots_adjust(top=0.8,bottom=0.05,left=0.01,right=0.99)
maps=[m for m in cm.datad if not m.endswith("_r")]
maps.sort()
l=len(maps)+1
for i, m in enumerate(maps):
    subplot(1,l,i+1)
    axis("off")
    imshow(a,aspect='auto',cmap=get_cmap(m),origin="lower")
    title(m,rotation=90,fontsize=10)
savefig("colormaps.png",dpi=100,facecolor='gray')
display("colormaps.png")
```

But when I tried to run in, it says `no module named show_graph`

Comment: Where did you get the line `from show_graph import display`?

Comment: The third line.. Since I don't have any idea on how to display this graph

Comment: @ErikaSawajiri As far I know, there is no module named `show_graph`, other than if you have created a local one yourself. Therefore the interpreter will raise an `ImportError` when trying to import this module. Where have you seen the `show_graph` module used earlier?

Comment: I forgot where I saw it. So, is there any other way to display the graph? @nordev

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should remove the `from show_graph import display`, as this import raises an `ImportError`. Then your code to save and show the plot could e.g. be like this

```
from pylab import *
from numpy import outer
rc('text', usetex=False)
a=outer(arange(0,1,0.01),ones(10))
figure(figsize=(10,5))
subplots_adjust(top=0.8,bottom=0.05,left=0.01,right=0.99)
maps=[m for m in cm.datad if not m.endswith("_r")]
maps.sort()
l=len(maps)+1
for i, m in enumerate(maps):
    subplot(1,l,i+1)
    axis("off")
    imshow(a,aspect='auto',cmap=get_cmap(m),origin="lower")
    title(m,rotation=90,fontsize=10)
savefig("colormaps.png",dpi=100,facecolor='gray')
show()
```